# Adapt fatFS library to PIC32

Tags: pic, sd, fat

I'm developing an application with PIC32MX, that record 3 WAV sounds and store theme into SD. Unfortunately the speed that I have reach is 155 kB/s and is insufficient for my application. Then I have to move fatFS, that use multi sector write speed wich seems to solve my problem. I download the latest library for fatFS [here](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html) (bottom of the page). I read on the internet that this code is generic and only some part of code needs to be adapted, based on microcontroller in use.
I have spent many time trying to understand what are this portions of code, but I still dont'find theme.
Anyone can help me?

EDIT: Finally I understand how to modify the fatFS for adapt it to my system.
But I have a little poblem. After I properly modified the "platform dependent" section with correct SPI and chip select pin, I tryied to compile. I obtained an error about windows.h and tchar.h, included in file integer.h. But in integer.h I see the ifdef, and I want compile the "embedded" section, not the windows section. If I try to delete the ifdef, I obtained this error: " ';' expected but 'fs_type' found ". This come from typedef struct of ff.h.
On internet there are project with the identical structure, why this doesn't compile?

Answer (score 1):

Microchip Harmony and MLA both contain good fast file access libraries, supporting multiple backing stores including SD, MMC, CF-II, USB MSD, etc.  I suggest you give them a go since they are already tailored to the PIC32 chips.

Comment: What is meant by a "blacking store"?

Comment: Typo - ignore the "l". Should be "backing stores". Computing term. Look it up.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I'm using mikroC. I haven't problem to work at register level, setting the single register for SPI comunication, if needed. But I can't use library made for other system, such as Harmony and MLA. For this reason I choose fatFS, because I read wich is indipendent from microcontroller (and compilator I think), and it only needs to change few basic low-level commands; but I can't find these.